# QProgressbar with 2 Labels with differend alignment

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressbar

When a Client connects to my application a new `QProgressbar` will show and display his set name and display some more information. This works fine. But based on the length of the name it doesn't look perfect if multiple people connect. And it is getting harder to read.

What i want is two labels. One For the name which is left aligned and one on the right side for the other information with right alignment

[image: Here a visual example what i want]

So is there a way to display two different labels on top of the progressbar and have one aligned to the left and one to the right?

Comment: Could you provide a picture of how those labels should be positioned relative to the progress bar?

Comment: [Picture as in post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UJOIs.png) both Labels should be centered vertically. And one should be aligned left (horizontal) and the other one to the right (horizontal aswell)

Comment: And where is the progress bar?

Comment: That blue thing is my progressbar. Sorry for hustle. Here's a more clear version: [New Picture](http://i.imgur.com/5THBEpT.png)

Comment: It seems to me you should create yours progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such behaviour is not provided by standard Progress Bar, you must subclass and implement your behaviour yourself.